# How can I send an SMS with an Esp8266 Sparkfun Wifi shield and Arduino?

Tags: sms, arduino-uno, esp8266

I am currently trying to send a message through an Arduino Uno using the Sparkfun esp2866 Wifi Shield. I have already set up a Twilio and Temboo account. Using Temboo and the Sparkfun esp2866 shield library I have generated the code below with all my personal information taken out.

I have not included the other file in my code which includes all my Temboo account information.

When I try to run the program, the shield connects to my wifi network, however it doesn't send the text message to my cell phone. I don't have much experiences working with IOT devices and I was wondering if anyone could help. Any input is appreciated!

Thank you in advance!

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h> 
#include <SparkFunESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <Temboo.h>
#include "TembooAccount.h" 

const char mySSID[] = "ssid ";
const char myPSK[] = " password";

ESP8266Client client;


int numRuns = 1;   // Execution count, so this doesn't run forever
int maxRuns = 10; 

void setup() 
{
  // Serial Monitor is used to control the demo and view
  // debug information.
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.println("Serial started");
  serialTrigger(F("Press any key to begin."));

  // initializeESP8266() verifies communication with the WiFi
  // shield, and sets it up.
  initializeESP8266();

  // connectESP8266() connects to the defined WiFi network.
  connectESP8266();

  // displayConnectInfo prints the Shield's local IP
  // and the network it's connected to.
  displayConnectInfo();


}

void loop() 
{
    if (numRuns <= maxRuns) {
    Serial.println("Running SendSMS - Run #" + String(numRuns++));
    delay(1000);
    TembooChoreo SendSMSChoreo(client);

    // Invoke the Temboo client
    SendSMSChoreo.begin();

    // Set Temboo account credentials
    SendSMSChoreo.setAccountName(TEMBOO_ACCOUNT);
    SendSMSChoreo.setAppKeyName(TEMBOO_APP_KEY_NAME);
    SendSMSChoreo.setAppKey(TEMBOO_APP_KEY);

    // Set Choreo inputs
    String AuthTokenValue = "";
    SendSMSChoreo.addInput("AuthToken", AuthTokenValue);
    String ToValue = "";
    SendSMSChoreo.addInput("To", ToValue);
    String FromValue = "";
    SendSMSChoreo.addInput("From", FromValue);
    String BodyValue = "Hello World";
    SendSMSChoreo.addInput("Body", BodyValue);
    String AccountSIDValue = "";
    SendSMSChoreo.addInput("AccountSID", AccountSIDValue);

    // Identify the Choreo to run
    SendSMSChoreo.setChoreo("/Library/Twilio/SMSMessages/SendSMS");

    // Run the Choreo; when results are available, print them to serial
    SendSMSChoreo.run();
    Serial.println("DONE!");
    while(SendSMSChoreo.available()) {
      char c = SendSMSChoreo.read();
      Serial.print(c);
    }
    SendSMSChoreo.close();
  }

  Serial.println("\nWaiting...\n");
  delay(30000); // wait 30 seconds between SendSMS calls
}


void initializeESP8266()
{
  // esp8266.begin() verifies that the ESP8266 is operational
  // and sets it up for the rest of the sketch.
  // It returns either true or false -- indicating whether
  // communication was successul or not.
  // true
  int test = esp8266.begin();
  if (test != true)
  {
    Serial.println(F("Error talking to ESP8266."));
    errorLoop(test);
  }
  Serial.println(F("ESP8266 Shield Present"));
}

void connectESP8266()
{
  // The ESP8266 can be set to one of three modes:
  //  1 - ESP8266_MODE_STA - Station only
  //  2 - ESP8266_MODE_AP - Access point only
  //  3 - ESP8266_MODE_STAAP - Station/AP combo
  // Use esp8266.getMode() to check which mode it's in:
  int retVal = esp8266.getMode();
  if (retVal != ESP8266_MODE_STA)
  { // If it's not in station mode.
    // Use esp8266.setMode([mode]) to set it to a specified
    // mode.
    retVal = esp8266.setMode(ESP8266_MODE_STA);
    if (retVal < 0)
    {
      Serial.println(F("Error setting mode."));
      errorLoop(retVal);
    }
  }
  Serial.println(F("Mode set to station"));

  // esp8266.status() indicates the ESP8266's WiFi connect
  // status.
  // A return value of 1 indicates the device is already
  // connected. 0 indicates disconnected. (Negative values
  // equate to communication errors.)
  retVal = esp8266.status();
  if (retVal <= 0)
  {
    Serial.print(F("Connecting to "));
    Serial.println(mySSID);
    // esp8266.connect([ssid], [psk]) connects the ESP8266
    // to a network.
    // On success the connect function returns a value >0
    // On fail, the function will either return:
    //  -1: TIMEOUT - The library has a set 30s timeout
    //  -3: FAIL - Couldn't connect to network.
    retVal = esp8266.connect(mySSID, myPSK);
    if (retVal < 0)
    {
      Serial.println(F("Error connecting"));
      errorLoop(retVal);
    }
  }
}

void displayConnectInfo()
{
  char connectedSSID[24];
  memset(connectedSSID, 0, 24);
  // esp8266.getAP() can be used to check which AP the
  // ESP8266 is connected to. It returns an error code.
  // The connected AP is returned by reference as a parameter.
  int retVal = esp8266.getAP(connectedSSID);
  if (retVal > 0)
  {
    Serial.print(F("Connected to: "));
    Serial.println(connectedSSID);
  }

  // esp8266.localIP returns an IPAddress variable with the
  // ESP8266's current local IP address.
  IPAddress myIP = esp8266.localIP();
  Serial.print(F("My IP: ")); Serial.println(myIP);
}



// errorLoop prints an error code, then loops forever.
void errorLoop(int error)
{
  Serial.print(F("Error: ")); Serial.println(error);
  Serial.println(F("Looping forever."));
  for (;;)
    ;
}

// serialTrigger prints a message, then waits for something
// to come in from the serial port.
void serialTrigger(String message)
{
  Serial.println();
  Serial.println(message);
  Serial.println();
  while (!Serial.available())
    ;
  while (Serial.available())
    Serial.read();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I work at [Temboo](http://temboo.com).

While we don't officially support the ESP8266, we've found a couple of forum posts in which people have been able to get Temboo to work with the ESP8266. Here you go:

http://www.esp8266.com/viewtopic.php?p=24019

https://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=337186.0

If that doesn't help, feel free to contact [Temboo Support](http://temboo.com/support) and we'll do our best to help figure out what's going wrong for you.

The key piece of info you need to be aware of is that you need to modify following Temboo library files:

```
\Arduino\libraries\Temboo\src\Temboo.cpp

\Arduino\libraries\Temboo\src\utility\
--ChoreoInputFormatter
--ChoreoOutputFormatter
--ChoreoPresetFormatter
--TembooSession
--tmbhmac
--tmbmd5
```

You need to modify all occurances of "avr/pgmspace.h" in these files, changing it to"pgmspace.h".

Comment: Thanks - I've updated the original answer based on your comment.